# Converting a Lua function chunk to a C string

Tags: c++, lua

I am working on a project that takes a Lua string and converts it into a C string – not at all difficult, of course. However, I run into trouble when attempting to convert a binary representation of a function, i.e. one produced by a call to `string.dump`, to a C string. I am having trouble reading the entire string.

While it is not the ultimate goal of the project, consider the following simple example where I print out the characters in a string one-by-one using a C function called `chars` that I have registered for use in Lua:

```
static void chars(char* cp) {
    char* pointer = cp;
    while (*pointer) {
        printf("%c\n", *pointer);
        ++pointer;
    }
    return;
}

static int lua_chars(lua_State* L) {
    lua_len(L, 1);
    size_t len = static_cast<size_t>(lua_tonumber(L, -1)) + 1;
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    if (len > 0) {
        char* cp = static_cast<char*>(malloc(len));
        strcat(cp, lua_tostring(L, 1));
        chars(cp);
        free(cp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Calling `chars` from a Lua script would look like this:

```
chars("Hello World!")
```

and would print out the characters one by one with each followed by a newline.

Now to the actual issue. Consider this example where I declare a function in Lua, dump it with `string.dump`, and then pass that string to the function `chars` to print out its characters individually:

```
local function foo()
    print("foo")
    return
end

local s = assert(string.dump(foo))
chars(s)
```

The string `s` in its entirety, not printed with my function `chars`, looks something like this:

```
uaS?

xV(w@=stdin@A@$@&?&?printfoo_ENV
```

However, `chars` only prints the first five bytes:

```
u
a
S
```

(Note there are supposed to be two lines of whitespace before the 'u'.)

I am almost certain that this is due to null characters within the string, which I think interferes with `lua_tostring`'s functionality.  I have come across `lua_Writer` for reading chunks, but I have no idea how to use/code it. How can I successfully convert the entire string on the Lua stack to a C string?

Comment: Please only tag the language(s) you're actually programming in.

Comment: See `lua_tolstring`, which gives you a pointer to the bytes and the number of bytes in a Lua string.

Comment: If you use C++, you should use `std::string` or `std::string_view`, which are safer to use and do not depend on null characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am almost certain that this is due to null characters within the
>   string

Yes, it's exactly because Lua strings can contain zeroes.

> which I think interferes with lua_tostring's functionality.

And this is false. `lua_tostring()` works as intended. It's just `strcat()` you're using will only copy the data up to the nearest zero byte.

If you need to copy the string, use `memcpy`, passing it both the pointer to Lua string data and Lua string length (`lua_len`, `lua_rawlen`, etc).

But just for printing you don't even need to copy anything. Pass the `len` variable as an argument to `chars()`, and check that length instead of waiting for zero byte.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem isn't `lua_tostring` but `strcat` which copies until it finds an null characters. Same Problem with your `chars` function.
That should work:

```
memcpy(cp, lua_tostring(L, 1), len);
chars(cp, len);
...
static void chars(char* cp, size_t len) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i, ++cp) {
        putchar(*cp);
    }
}
```